# Refactring in CLion isn't working

Tags: c++, refactoring, clion

I have problem with refactoring, e.g. renaming classes in CLion. CLion shows me the refactoring windows, but doesn't find anything to refactor. Screenshots are appended. I also tried to add header files into CMakeLists, but without success. Do you have any idea what I should do?
Thank you.
[image]
[image]

Edit: I am using Debian 8.2 x64 with Cinnamon

Comment: What happens when you click the Refactor button? What is your version of CLion?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just added all .h files into CMakeLists.txt into `set(SOURCE_FILES ....)` and now its work fine. 
Thanks to V-R.

Comment: Can you share an example of the project, what was the original `CMakeLists.txt` and what it became?

Answer (score 3):

If renaming doesn't work, it could be because your project does not successfully build. Try it with a simplest project, e.g. create a completely new Hello World program. I'm sure if it builds successfully, refactoring will work as well. Worked for me in CLion 1.2.4 on OS X 10.9.4.

Concerning `CMakeLists.txt`, it is a standard file that is created automatically by CLion if you create a new project. If you have an existing project, you will find `CMakeLists.txt` if you open the menu `View->Tool Windows->Project`.

My advice is to experiment by closing your existing project (`File->Close Project`), creating a New Project and playing around with the CLion features. Here is a nice [Quick Start Guide for CLion](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/help/quick-start-guide.html)

Comment: Build is successful and program works fine. But refactoring works only for local variable. When I want etc. rename class name, CLion doesnt find usage of that class. BUt when I use "Find usages", its find all occurance of that class. 
I am working on Debian 8.2.0 and Clion 1.2.4 (last release). 
Maybe there could be problem, that I have whole class (definitions + declarations) defined in .h file (because of school - i need split all files into one), but I tried add that files into CMakeList.txt without any change.

Comment: does class renaming work for you in a simplest Hello World project?

Comment: Ou, I got it. CLion needs add every .h file into CMakeList.txt.